# Getting error "The [standard] token filter has been removed." when running a query for free text search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to run the below query

```
GET /MyIndex_2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and i am getting the exception "The [standard] token filter has been removed"

this query i am using to do a text search in all the fields, the same query is running in my development server but in production its not working

Below is the settings for my index

```
PUT analyzed_accounts_consolidated10052020_azure_prod4
{
  "settings": {
    
  
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "max_result_window": "10000000",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "synonym_filter_cvtext": {
              "ignore_case": "true",
              "expand": "true",
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "ho2s_filters/synonyms_cvtext.txt"
            },
            "stemmer_it": {
              "type": "stemmer",
              "language": "light_italian"
            },
            "synonym_filter_skills_roles": {
              "ignore_case": "true",
              "expand": "true",
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "ho2s_filters/synonyms_skills_roles.txt"
            },
            "stopwords_it": {
              "type": "stop",
              "stopwords_path": "ho2s_filters/stopwords.txt"
            },
            "synonym_filter_educations": {
              "ignore_case": "true",
              "expand": "true",
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "ho2s_filters/synonyms_educations.txt"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "analyzer_skills_roles": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "synonym_filter_skills_roles",
                "stopwords_it",
                "stemmer_it"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "mapping_skills_roles"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "case_insensitive_sort": {
              "filter": [
                "standard",
                "lowercase",
                "trim"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
            },
            "analyzer_cvtext": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "synonym_filter_cvtext",
                "stopwords_it",
                "stemmer_it"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "mapping_skills_roles"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "analyzer_educations": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "synonym_filter_educations",
                "stopwords_it",
                "stemmer_it"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "mapping_skills_roles"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          },
          "char_filter": {
            "mapping_skills_roles": {
              "type": "mapping",
              "mappings_path": "ho2s_filters/mapping_skills_roles.txt"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
        
        
      }
    
}
}
```

Any suggestion to get this resolved

Answer (score 0):

The `standard` token filter [has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/analysis-standard-tokenfilter.html) in ES 7 because it was just a placeholder not doing anything.

You need to remove them from your `case_insensitive_sort` analyzer

```
        "case_insensitive_sort": {
          "filter": [
            "standard",             <----- remove this
            "lowercase",
            "trim"
          ],
```